# How to change the background color of Active links in a menu bar?

Tags: html, css

I copied the following code from 
[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) 
 and added it to all pages on my website. Navigation is working fine, but Background color of active links in the menu doesn't change.

How can I fix this?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/home.php">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/news.php">News</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `:focus`?

Comment: Do you mean the background color on hover?

Comment: You want to do it only through css or js

Comment: Yes I mean it ,I am new in css .please help me

Comment: Do you have news.php, contact.php etc seperately with the menu. If it is unique on all the page then you can just style it based on the page. If no you can achieve it through JS or jquery.

Comment: @Sasi I am looking for a solution with css

Comment: The background color is changing in hover and active.

Comment: @Starkeen I think what you want is not only change the background color on hover and active, but also you want the different background color remains until the user chooses the next page. Right?

Comment: `:active` in css isn't checking the url and link href to be the same, if this is what you are trying to achieve :) also, you have a mistake on this line `<ahref="/home.php"...`, there is no space `<a href=`

Comment: Add a separate a:active block if you want the colours to be different on both hover and while clicking.

Comment: I want something like this : when I go to about.php , background color of **about** should change. but it is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a CSS class on the active page. Here i added `class="active"`

> Change CSS as below

```
a:hover,
a:active,
a.active {
  background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

> On **home.php** change the navigation code as below.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/home.php" class="active">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/news.php">News</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> On **news.php** make the change as below, Similarly for other pages

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/home.php">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/news.php" class="active">News</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```